Error during ee.initialize: TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'Classifier' in undefined
I'm using the @google/earthengine npm package within an Angular app. This is the code that handles authentication and then tries to initalize the framework:
    async handleAuthCallback(tokens: any) {
        await new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
          ee.data.authenticateViaOauth( 
            this.CLIENT_ID,
            () => {
              ee.initialize( 
                null,
                null,
                () => {
                  console.log('EE initialized successfully');
                  resolve();
                },
                (initError: any) => {
                  console.error('Error during ee.initialize:', initError); ** here **
                  reject(initError);
                }
              );
            },
            (authError: any) => {
              console.error('Error during ee.data.authenticateViaOauth:', authError);
              reject(authError);
            }
          );
        });
 
     }

After successfully authenticated (via ee.data.authenticateViaOauth), the ee.initialize gives me this error:
auth.service.ts:29 Error during ee.initialize: 
TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'Classifier' in undefined
    at ee.initializeGeneratedClasses_ (browser.js:31939:30)
    at ee.initializationSuccess_ (browser.js:31805:374)
    at module$contents$ee$apiclient_Call.callback (browser.js:29341:34)
    at callback (browser.js:25665:45)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:339:158)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.mjs:7020:25)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:339:46)
    at _ZoneImpl.run (zone.js:110:35)
    at zone.js:2428:30
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:364:171)


Were you able to find a solution for this? Facing the same issue

No luck yet unfortunately :(

I'm able to replicate it too. It fails due to exportedEE being undefined in https://github.com/google/earthengine-api/blob/6878dad75376a1df9aa294431d22faa92f6dc334/javascript/src/ee.js#L558. It's declare like so: const exportedEE = goog.global['ee'];. I have no idea for workarounds, unfortunately. Try to submit a bug report: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=184406&template=1254745

Done: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/364508687

I've finally found a solution after some help from Google.
Instead of compiling ee.* into Angular code, I set it up as an externs.js model where Angular expects symbols in the global namespace.
That's what I did:

Declared in global namespace: declare var ee: any;
Add a src
import in the html:

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/earthengine/1.1.0/earthengine-api.min.js"></script>
Source: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/364508687

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
